# Angular project doesn't answer to my request

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I am facing a problem on my angular project dockerized.

During the startup of my container it seems that the 4200 port used for the project is already used, even if the CMD of the container is not the startup of the application.
In fact my docker looks like:

```
FROM node:11.10.1

ARG major
ARG minor
ARG sourceCodeReference
ARG productNumber
ARG revision
ARG timestamp

LABEL major=$major
LABEL minor=$minor
LABEL sourceCodeReference=$sourceCodeReference
LABEL productNumber=$productNumber
LABEL revision=$revision
LABEL timestamp=$timestamp

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/


COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install 
RUN printf "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ jessie main\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main\ndeb-src http:/
/security.debian.org jessie/updates main" > /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/
COPY dash.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
RUN ln -s /usr/src/app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng /usr/sbin/ng

#CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
CMD ["sleep", "infinity"]
```

Considering that problem I have changed the configuration of my project, using a different port: 4201 but when I try to navigate in my angular application running (this time) I don't receive any answer.

What could be the issue? How I can verify that there aren't problems locking the application ?

Here the logout of the application starting: (manually on  port 4200)

```
 10% building 4/4 modules 0 activeExpress server listening on port 4200      
events.js:173
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:4200
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1256:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1304:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1443:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:63:10)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1283:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
root@5abd5b6fa13d:/usr/src/app#  --prodps au^C
root@5abd5b6fa13d:/usr/src/app# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   4188   676 ?        Ss   15:13   0:00 sleep infinity
root         7  0.0  0.0  18252  3324 pts/0    Ss   15:13   0:00 bash
root        31  0.5  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Z    15:15   0:00 [node] <defunct
root        38  0.0  0.0  36636  2776 pts/0    R+   15:17   0:00 ps aux
root@5abd5b6fa13d:/usr/src/app#
```

Before to start the defunct node was not running and apparently the 4200 is not used by other processes:

Instead when I change the port to 4201 the startup phase looks good: (but I am still not able to load my angular project via chrome)

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4201, open your browser on https://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building 4/4 modules 0 activeExpress server listening on port 4201      
 40% building 145/145 modules 0 active                                           
MongoDb connected !!!

Date: 2019-11-21T13:35:39.337Z
Hash: ef9332be02eca07b14c4
Time: 147804ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js, runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js.map (runtime) 1.46 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} es2015-polyfills.d4e1d1f26e719a5dba37.js, es2015-polyfills.d4e1d1f26e719a5dba37.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 56.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} main.6c559f8f936550d86d03.js, main.6c559f8f936550d86d03.js.map (main) 2.33 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills.e65198f4c10e2cae53b9.js, polyfills.e65198f4c10e2cae53b9.js.map (polyfills) 41.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.421c2a405fa16d4f5f7f.css, styles.421c2a405fa16d4f5f7f.css.map (styles) 315 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.086b20530ca3f0670b5f.js, scripts.086b20530ca3f0670b5f.js.map (scripts) 1.04 MB [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in budgets, maximum exceeded for initial. Budget 2 MB was exceeded by 1.78 MB.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

I am a bit confused.

```
      netstat -nltp
root@1df394cfdaed:/usr/src/app# netstat -nltp 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      335/myappl.cert 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42897        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::4201                 :::*                    LISTEN      335/myappl.cert 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      335/myappl.cert
```

Should I have a service listening on :80 ?

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
1df394cfdaed        myapplication:13.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes            0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4201->4201/tcp   scripts_myappl_1
```

Comment: can you share what `netstat -nltp` outputs?

Comment: How are you running the image? Are you exposing 4201 with the docker run -p 4201:4201?

Comment: @MarkS yes, in the way you are saying, 0.0.0.0:4201->4201/tcp

Comment: @aomerk : I have put the result in the question

Comment: just do `kill 335`

Comment: @aomerk, by doing kill command then the "ng" is stopping to serve, even if it is not serving any requests :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related the default port used for ng server (4200).
The same port is used in my code (server.js)

```
// Node express server setup. 
var app = express();
app.set('port', 4200);
```

By changing the port to 443 (ng serve --port 443) and restoring the usage of 4200 then it worked.